# How to add additional cshtml to MVC project?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I want to add a page to MVC project (.NET Core 3.1) that will be opened on request.

Like I click the button (example only) -> "www.heremypage.com" and the page will be opened.

My questions are:

1. Where have I place it? Under wwwroot? Or in views?
2. How to connect this page to my URL? Can I do it in Index.cshtml or in _ViewStart.cshtml?

Thank you!

Comment: You would place it in Views, you would create a method that will server this view on a Controller of choice (I assume there is one). I recommend reading an .NET MVC tutorial first though, there's a lot of basics you need to learn so you can understand the concept better.

Answer (score 0):

e.g. you want to create a page: Products:

- Create a Folder under Views with the Name: "Products"
- Create a MVC Controller: "ProductsController", this is gonna control that page / provide it.
- Inside that Controller, there is a Method called Index: `public IActionResult Index()`, this method is gonna look in the "Products" Folder, it looks for an index.cshtml file. Create that file in that folder. This "Route" represents the `/` Path, or in this case (maybe): /Products/. Its like the index.html, usually the first html file thats gonna be used in a Directory.
- Alternativly you can give that file another name, but you need to specify in the controller: `return View("<Name of your File without .cshtml")

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-view?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio